# MIssing parent reference in a bidirectional hibernate mapping

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jackson

I have a spring rest backend  with two entities with a bidirectional relationshop (one-to-many, many to one). To overcome nested fetching issues, @JsonManagedReference/@JsonBackReference has been used for a perent/child relationship between entities.

The entites look as this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Parent")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Parent implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private List<Child> childList;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    public List<Child> getChildList() {
        return childList;
    }

    public void setChildListe(List<Child> childListe) {
            this.childList = childList;
        }

    }


@Entity
@Table(name = "Child")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Child implements java.io.Serializable {


    private Integer id;
    private Parent parent;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ParentID")
    @JsonBackReference
    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }


}
```

This works fine when fetching the Parent element, the childset is then fetched alongside and displayed as an json-array.

However, there is no reference to parent in the child element due to the usage of jsonbackreferance.
How can solve this issue ? I need parent reference when fetching child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would lead to an infinite loop when serializing to JSON. That's the whole reason we don't do bi-direction JSON relationships.

What I would do is add an additional column to the child entity if you need the ID alone.

```
private Integer parentId;

@Column(name = "ParentID", insertable=false, updateable=false)
public Integer getParentId() {
    return parentId;
}
```